# Is it correct to use kwargs in the following scenario of python code?

Tags: python

Is it correct to use kargs in the following scenario?

I have a function that needs five parameters in the call with two of them optional. So, I can delete it as:

```
def f(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, o1=None, o2=None)
```

or

```
def f(**kwargs)
```

Because I'm doing things like this with the params:

```
orig_path = "{0}/{1}/{3}/{4}".format(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

or

```
orig_path = "{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/{p4}".format(kwargs)
```

I don't know which style is the correct way in Python to use in the declarations. Is there any guide to look for the correct use of kwargs?. I've seen in the Amazon boto3 api usually uses the kwargs construction but...

Comment: Use the first. The functio-def alone then tells that 5 params are needed. This is some kind of information gain. It could also save some code inside the function. (Assumption: p1-p5 are required)

Comment: @sascha You could likely make that into an answer and mention the "explicit is better than implicit" principle from the Zen of Python.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Feel free to go for it as your mentioning of the Zen of Python is very relevant here.

Comment: @sascha Well, it's basically nothing else than what you already said ("This is some kind of information gain."), only with different words :)

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, you should always write out all parameters in a function definition, if you can, and ideally give them descriptive names.

The [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says

> Explicit is better than implicit.

and also

> Readability counts.

Making the parameters explicit helps you prevent many mistakes, like calling the function with too many or too few parameters or with keyword parameters that don't exist.

It also helps readability a lot, as you can easily spot from the definition how many and which parameters the function expects and in which order and what the defaults for possible keyword parameters are. Sometimes, you can even guess what the function does via good parameter names without having to look at the documentation.

Some IDEs can even look up the definition automatically when you write a call and alert you to possible problems while you're typing.

Do this:

```py
def twiddle_knobs(tuning, volume, panning=None, bass=6.0, midrange=-2.0, treble=1.5):
    """Modify the most important radio controls."""

    my_radio.modify_control(radio.TUNEFREQ, value=max(min(tuning, 120.0), 85.0))
    my_radio.modify_control(radio.VOL_MASTER, value=(volume / 100.0))

    if panning is not None:
        my_radio.modify_control(radio.VOL_LEFT, value=min(1.0 - panning / 100.0, 1.0))
        my_radio.modify_control(radio.VOL_RIGHT, value=min(1.0 + panning / 100.0, 1.0))

    for control, value in ((radio.EQU_BASS, bass),
                           (radio.EQU_MID,  midrange),
                           (radio.EQU_TREB, treble)):

        my_radio.modify_control(control, value=value, unit=radio.DB)
```

Do not do this:

```py
def twiddle_knobs(*args, **kwargs):  # WARNING: never do this!
    my_radio.modify_control(radio.TUNEFREQ, max(min(args[0], 120.0), 85.0))
    my_radio.modify_control(radio.VOL_MASTER, args[1] / 100.0)

    if kwargs.get("panning") is not None:
        my_radio.modify_control(radio.VOL_LEFT, min(1.0 - kwargs["panning"] / 100.0, 1.0))
        my_radio.modify_control(radio.VOL_RIGHT, min(1.0 + kwargs["panning"] / 100.0, 1.0))

    for control, param, default in ((radio.EQU_BASS, "bass",      6.0),
                                    (radio.EQU_MID,  "midrange", -2.0),
                                    (radio.EQU_TREB, "treble",    1.5)):

        my_radio.modify_control(control, kwargs.get(param, default), radio.DB)
```

So when is it OK to use `*args` and `*kwargs`?

- One use for `*args` is when you need to receive a list of things that
  are **alike and serve the same function**. However, you could also
  just use a normal parameter and have the caller explicitly pass in a
  list. Sometimes, calling the function with `func([thing])` can seem
  awkward, though, particularly when most of the time you pass only one
  thing or no thing at all. Those are the times when `*args` would
  improve the situation.
- Also, when you need to **pass** some of the positional and/or keyword
  arguments your function received **on to another function you don't
  have control over** and you don't want to dictate which parameters your
  caller is allowed to have handed through, then `*args` and `*kwargs` -
  *used after your explicit parameters* - are the way to achieve that.
- If you have a set of keyword parameters that serve a **strongly
  related function and you cannot exactly predefine upfront what the
  keywords will be**, because they might depend upon something that's
  dynamically changing, that would also be a good reason for using
  `*kwargs`.

This list is not exhaustive, but it should give you a general idea.